# match two string in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've two strings, `check_url` and `curr_url`

```
<script>
var check_url='http://localhost/project/show/{dynamic content}';
var locationHref    =   $(location).attr('href');//current url
</script>
```

In this I need to match both strings.
I tried below code

```
var urlslugRegex = '/^[a-z0-9-]+$/'; 
if(locationHref == 'http://localhost/project/show/'+(urlslugRegex)){
    alert("if");
}else{
    alert("else");
}
```

Comment: Do you want check if One string matches the other string?

Comment: yes...but i wont get the dynamic content in this page...only regular expression i can use

Comment: instead you can use `window.location.href;`

Comment: I think you need to be more precise of what you're trying to do.

Comment: pls check my updated question

Comment: You may want to look at `.match(regex)` function.

Comment: i tried .match(regex) its not working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
var urlslugRegex = '([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)'; 
if(locationHref.match('http://localhost/project/show/'+(urlslugRegex)){
    alert("if");
}else{
    alert("else");
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this :

```
var urlslugRegex = /^http\:\/\/localhost\/project\/show\/[-a-z0-9]+$/; 
if(locationHref.match(urlslugRegex)){
   alert("if");
}else{
   alert("else");
}
```

Note: In a character set, "-" should be placed carefully, since it is used as a special character for character ranges. Better to put at the beginning of the character set.